# Unclear first step in proof of the Schwarz Integral Formula.

Tags: complex-analysis

I am revising for an exam, and the following (first) step in the proof of Schwarz Integral Formula is presented without derivation. I don't understand it, can somebody help?

"$\Gamma$ is a circle (perifery) $|z-z_0|=R$, $f(z)$ is analytic inside and continuous on the boundary of the circle $C(R,z_0)$.

Applying Cauchy Integral Formula, $f(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\Gamma}{\frac{f(t)dt}{t-z}}$, $z\in C(R,z_0)$.

*now is the part i don't understand:*

Then $0=\int_{\Gamma}{\frac{f(t)dt}{t-z^{*}}}$, where $z^{*}=z_0+\frac{R^2}{\bar{z}-\bar{z_0}}$. (Why?)"

Comment: So, is $\Gamma=C(R,z_0)$? Then, we have $(z-z_0)(\bar z-\bar z_0)=R^2$, thus $z^*=z_0+(z-z_0)=z$.

Comment: @Berci $t$ varies over $\Gamma$ but OP didn't say what $z$ is. Are you taking $z$ on $\Gamma$?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Yes, it was not really clear. But $z\in C(R, z_0) $ is also written.

Comment: @Berci I may be missing something here. The integral does not exist (in general) when  $z$ is on the circle, right? OP wants to show that the integral is $0$!

Comment: @berci I think z lies inside the contour Г, it is t that you can write this equality for. I've thought about it and I think I can answer my question now. Since z lies inside, there will be inequality, and the denominator is never zero. Hence, by cauchy integral theorem, the function inside the integral is analytic and the integral is 0

Comment: @berci $C(R, z_0)$ is the inner area of the circle, its a 2 dimensional object, while Г should be its boundary then

Comment: @NickTheDick You have to take $z$ outside the contour. See my answer.

Comment: @kaviramamurthy I forgot to write it, but this equality of the integral to 0 holds for points $z\in C(R, z_0)$,just like the cauchy integral formula above it. Not outside it! Are you sure with your answer?

Comment: @NickTheDick You are right. I made a mistake. I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$z^{*}$ is outside the circle of radius $R$ around $z_0$ if $z$ is inside it.  This makes the integrand analytic so it is $0$ by Cauchy's Theorem.